# Default Qty For Simple Products Associated to Grouped Products Not Saving

Tags: grouped-products, associated-products

In a grouped product, associated simple products default quantity not saving.
The values are saved in database in catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal table, but not showing in admin (blank input on product save) or frontend.

Comment: Which magento version you used? Have you check concole or magento log file? Is there any error?

Comment: Magento version 1.9.3.6. There's no errors in system or exception.log

Comment: If you install any custom extension, please disable that and then check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. 
The shop owner created a product attribute with 'qty' attribute_code.

getQty() method was calling that attribute value instead of default magento qty.

After deleting that attribute the default qty values for simple products were saved in admin and appear on frontend